# How to apply a custom function to each column of my dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to get the hang of tidyverse and dplyr approaches, and want to apply the following function to each column of a dataframe / datatable:

```
library(multimode)
funx <- function(x) {multimode::modetest(x, method = 'SI') }
```

and then try to use something like summarize_all to start with, but I immediately get an error:

> Error: Column `mpg` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 8

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
     summarise_all(funx)
```

what I hope to end up with is a new dataframe that shows the colnames tested in column 1, and the p-value of the `modetest` in column 2

Since yesterday (23-05-2019) after updating packages my solution fails to work and the following code now prints '.' dots instead of column names
submitted a post to the github page to ask about the cause of this change: [github](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4383)

```
library(multimode)
funx <- function(x) {
    print(substitute(x))
    multires <- multimode::modetest(x, method = 'SI') 
    p <- multires$p.value}

mtcars %>% 
    select(1:2) %>%
    summarise_all(list(~ funx(.)))
```

**UPDATE** Ironically, after getting feedback on the github post, with the new version we can now do this:

```
   mtcars %>%
      select(1:2) %>%
        summarise_all(funx)
```

Which, as you can see, is the exact same syntax as I started my problem with when posting this question. So, good work that the dplyr team has made the syntax more 'natural' I would say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `summarise` can output only with a single element.  According to `?summarise`

> Create one or more scalar variables summarizing the variables of an existing tbl. Tbls with groups created by group_by() will result in one row in the output for each group. Tbls with no groups will result in one row.

so if the output is more than length 1, wrap it in a `list` and `unnest`

```
library(dplyr)    
out <- mtcars %>%
          summarise_all(list(~ list(funx(.))))
```

If we are extracting a single value e.g. `p.value`, then no need to wrap it in a `list`

```
out1 <- mtcars %>% 
          select(1:2) %>%
          summarise_all(list(~ funx(.)$p.value))
out1
#    mpg   cyl
#1 0.718 0.244
```

It can be converted to a two column dataset with `gather`

```
library(tidyr)
gather(out1, colName, pvalue) %>%
      arrange(pvalue)
```

By checking the output of `modetest` on a single column

```
funx(mtcars[[1]])

#   Silverman (1981) critical bandwidth test

#data:  x
#Critical bandwidth = 2.5413, p-value = 0.716
#alternative hypothesis: true number of modes is greater than 1
```

it is not a single value output, but a summary model output.  So, it is better to store in a `list`, however, we can extract specific components (`p-value`) and output it in `summarise`

Comment: I was just about to say that there was a bracket missing, and after adding that I got an error related to your edit indeed haha. Any suggestion how to best extract the p-value in this approach?

Comment: @Mark Thanks, I added the bracket. For me, it is working `mtcars %>% select(1:2) %>% summarise_all(list(~ list(funx(.))))
                                                                                      mpg
1 2.54134750366211, 0.698, 1, greater, Silverman (1981) critical bandwidth test, 32, x, 0
                                                                                      cyl
1 1.31359100341797, 0.264, 1, greater, Silverman (1981) critical bandwidth test, 32, x, 0`

Comment: cool, that works nicely indeed. Would you know how to transpose the result in a 2 column output too, and sort it by increasing p value?

Comment: @Mark Just do `%>% gather %>% arrange(value)`

Comment: Ok, i added %>% rename(key = Parameter, value = p-value) to relabel them. Thanks for the help akrun!

Comment: in case you do export 2 or more variables, how would you split them into two columns here?

Comment: @Mark You may create a `tibble`, wrap it with a `list` and then `unnest`

Comment: akrun, do you know how I could print the column name being analyzed at the moment inside the funx()? I would like to use it to put that name into my sweetalert messages that I will build inside the function

Comment: @Mark  You can have a `print(substitute(.))` inside the `summarise` call

Comment: could you add the entire line of code? I'm confused with what you mean and can't find examples on google to make it work

Comment: @Mark What i meant is that inside the summarise_all, `summarise_all(list(~ {print(substitute(.)); list(funx(.))}))`

Comment: ah yes of course. I can also simply use substitute(y) inside funx to obtain it. I must have been overly focused on other things to forget about that simple solution

Comment: well, this is weird. it worked fine, but yesterday I updated all my packages and now the code prints just dots instead of column names (see update in the question)

Comment: @Mark Is that because the version that you have shows a different behavior with respect to handling the `list`.  I can't reproduce the issue though.  Tried it again and it is working for me

Comment: I don't know how to test the handling behaviour. I added the update to the post now

Comment: @Mark I used `packageVersion("dplyr")#
[1] ‘0.8.0.1’;  packageVersion("multimode")#
[1] ‘1.4’`

Comment: @Mark Can you try on a fresh session with loading only `library(dplyr);library(multimode)` and run the example in your post

Comment: just did, full restart, only those packages, printing dots still. it must be dplyr 0.8.1

Comment: @Mark Is that the CRAN version for `dplyr` or is it from `github`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193908/discussion-between-mark-and-akrun).